# Screen resolution of VM while running in console mode

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization

I have an application on my server that will take a screenshot of the desktop of the server while it's running. It's working well when I'm connected to the server with RDP, but when I disconnect, the resolution is decreased dramatically. It seems to be decreased to 640x480 if I'm not mistaken.

My server is a virtual server hosted by a third party and I do not know which hypervisor they use. I only have RDP access to it. I am using a [workaround](https://serverfault.com/questions/482352/take-screenshot-from-server-screen-while-disconnected-from-rdp%27) to send my current RDP session to the console. I run this command: `tscon <session#> /dest:console`

This works well, except for the fact that the resolution is decreased when the application I started is running in this session.

Does anyone know how I can increase the default resolution of the console session on a virtual machine?

Comment: Two down votes? Would anyone care to help me improve the question?

Comment: To increase the size of my virtual console, I go into `Q:\Utilites\DosBox\0.74\conf` ...  See the problem?  (Well, the main problem, at least).

Comment: Can you log into the console directly at the keyboard and set a resolution to something normal and then do your RDP session AFTER that?

Comment: @HopelessN00b I hoped that referencing the other question would allow people to see what I meant, rather than repeating the entire other ticket in here.

Comment: @TheCleaner I can only connect to it via RDP, which I think is always the case with a virtual server, even if you go to the physical server that's hosting the virtual server.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to get the impression that you're in way over your head here.  You can't seem to tell us what hypervisor you're using, and are under the impression that RDP is the only way to connect to a VM. (It's not.) ... this is just not enough to work with, and frankly, it looks very much like you're not able to give us enough to help you out, either.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I'm living up to your name. I will elaborate on my question and add details from the old question rather than linking to it. Hope that it will be sufficient.

Comment: The answer will likely depend upon the OS of your host.  Unless I missed it, I don't see whether you're running Linux, Windows, or something else...  I assume Windows since you mention RDP, but something tells me there is an RDP for other OS.

Comment: It's Windows Server 2008. I put it on the ticket as a tag, but didn't include it in the question itself. I have no way to get information on the OS of the host server.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the resolution of the session would be changed to match the resolution of the (virtual) console it is being attached to. If 640x480 is not enough for your purposes, change it.

If you absolutely can't ask for console access from your hosting provider, installing [VNC](http://vnc.com/) and connecting to the VNC socket would give you the "physical" console screen and let you change the console resolution via GUI tools. You also could try either using the [QRes utility](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/QRes.shtml) or a [PowerShell script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/07/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-change-my-desktop-monitor-resolution-via-windows-powershell.aspx) to change the resolution via the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect with VNC in order to SET the good resolution in Console mode.

After you set the resolution you don't need VNC anymore and you can use mstsc.

When you know the compatible  resolution with the graphic card, you can automate the process with QRes tool : http://home.no/aksoftware/

Connect to the machine in mstsc and the this bat file : SwitchScreenResolution.bat

```
TSCON 2 /Dest:Console                --Replace 2 with the good Id Session (see in taskManager / Users Tab / ID value)
timeout 10
QRes.exe /x 1920 /y 1200          -- Replace with the compatible resolution (you can see all compatible resolution with VNC)
```

Answer (score 1):

One could use

```
powershell -Command "Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1920 -Height 1080 -Force"
```

From: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servercore/set-displayresolution?view=windowsserver2022-ps&viewFallbackFrom=win10-ps