# When disconnecting session keep active desktop session Windows server 2012

Tags: rdp

I have a VPS with Windows server 2012.
When disconnecting the remote connection with my physical computer, the desktop of the VPS becomes inactive, it logs off. However, I need to keep the virtual desktop active because I have macro's running using mouse and keyboardstrokes.

Is this possible? Or do I have to create something like a virtual machine?

thx!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/205902/how-to-keep-user-logged-in-when-disconnecting-from-rdp-session ?

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. However, when performing a macro with:
SendKeys "^(q)", True

It still says (excel): Run-time error ' 17' 
Can't perform requested operation. 

I get this also now when minimized the remote desktop connection..